# Adding Payment Method to woocommerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am adding a new payment method to woocommerce . I made a copy of paypal for my method. I want to call my functions when user made payment . So i want to know which class/function is called first when user return from paypal after making payment.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if any one else want to find out it calls the functions in class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php which is in shortcodes folder.